# Delphi - DataSnap - Rest - TServerMethods1

Tags: json, delphi, rest, datasnap

Estou realizando alguns testes do Datasnap com REST e json.

Lá na unit `ServerMethods`, que o próprio Delphi cria, tem a função `ReverseString`, mas bem, como consigo saber quem a enviou?

Gostaria de manter um *log* de informações dos clientes que chamaram este método.

Sei que poderia passar como parâmetro, mas ficaria cargo do cliente me passar essas informações, o que não quero, digamos que o método seria publico e varias clients fossem disparar esta informação. Posso perder fácil este controle, se não pegar a informação diretamente pelo controle do server.

Encontrei na web, que na unit `ServerConteiner`, tem um objeto `DSServer`, este objeto tem um evento chamado `OnConnect`, por ele consigo pegar os dados da seguinte forma:

```
procedure TServerContainer1.DSServer1Connect(
  DSConnectEventObject: TDSConnectEventObject);
begin
  DSConnectEventObject.ChannelInfo.ClientInfo.IpAddress;
  DSConnectEventObject.ChannelInfo.ClientInfo.ClientPort;
  DSConnectEventObject.ChannelInfo.ClientInfo.Protocol;
  DSConnectEventObject.ChannelInfo.ClientInfo.AppName;
end;
```

Mas não estou conseguindo encontrar como lá no `ServerMethods.ReverseString` eu consigo pegar estes dados.

Acredito que o processamento esteja em *thread* no servidor, por isso não posso passar este valor como global, pois ele pode pegar informação de outras conexões simultâneas.

No método `ReverseString`, tentei da seguinte forma:

```
var
    ADSServerClass : TDSServerClass;
begin
  ADSServerClass := TDSServerClass(GetOwner);
  TDSServer(ADSServerClass.Server).???
  // consegui chegar no server, mas não encontro, e não sei se é desta forma para localizar os dados de quem está me solicitando a execução do comando ReverseString 
end;
```

Comment: Solução em:  http://blog.atlabs.com.br/2017/06/delphi-pegando-o-ip-do-cliente-em-um.html

Answer (score 3):

Você só precisa de uma ligação entre o `DSServer1Connect` com as classes `ServerMethods`. A ideia aqui é armazenar as informações em um array por exemplo e recupera-las mais tarde de dentro do `ServerMethods`.

Antes de mais nada declare uma classe na unit `ServerConteiner`:

```
type
    TConexao = class
        IP: String;
        ClientPort: String;
        Protocol: String;
        AppName: String;
    end;
```

Depois disso, dentro do setor `public` do `ServerContainer` vamos criar uma variável para armazenar essas conexões, no caso será um `TDictionary`:

```
public
    ConnectionList: TDictionary<Integer, TConexao>;
```

Agora temos uma variável com alcance público, capaz de armazenar a informação de todas as conexões necessárias. Precisamos criá-la no evento `DataModuleCreate` do `ServerContainer`:

```
procedure TServerContainer1.DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    ConnectionList := TDictionary<Integer, TConexao>.Create;
end;
```

Com isso preparado, vamos fazer com que a `procedure TServerContainer1.DSServer1Connect` utilize essa variável:

```
procedure TServerContainer1.DSServer1Connect(
  DSConnectEventObject: TDSConnectEventObject);
var
    conexao: TConexao;
begin
    if ConnectionList.ContainsKey(TThread.CurrentThread.ThreadID) then
    begin
        ConnectionList[TThread.CurrentThread.ThreadID].IP := DSConnectEventObject.ChannelInfo.ClientInfo.IpAddress;
        ConnectionList[TThread.CurrentThread.ThreadID].ClientPort := DSConnectEventObject.ChannelInfo.ClientInfo.ClientPort;
        ConnectionList[TThread.CurrentThread.ThreadID].Protocol := DSConnectEventObject.ChannelInfo.ClientInfo.Protocol;
        ConnectionList[TThread.CurrentThread.ThreadID].AppName := DSConnectEventObject.ChannelInfo.ClientInfo.AppName;
    end
    else
    begin
        conexao := TConexao.Create;
        conexao.IP := DSConnectEventObject.ChannelInfo.ClientInfo.IpAddress;
        conexao.ClientPort := DSConnectEventObject.ChannelInfo.ClientInfo.ClientPort;
        conexao.Protocol := DSConnectEventObject.ChannelInfo.ClientInfo.Protocol;
        conexao.AppName := DSConnectEventObject.ChannelInfo.ClientInfo.AppName;
        ConnectionList.Add(TThread.CurrentThread.ThreadID, conexao);
    end;
end;
```

Armazenamos os valores dentro do `TDictionary`, e repare, antes de criar um novo registro vemos se ele já existe através da variável de localização global, que é a chave para esse dicionário `TThread.CurrentThread.ThreadID`.

Seria interessante também na desconexão remover esse registro para não ficar pesando em memória, logo o evento `TServerContainer1.DSServerDisconnect` ficaria:

```
procedure TServerContainer1.DSServerDisconnect(DSConnectEventObject: TDSConnectEventObject);
begin
    ConnectionList[TThread.CurrentThread.ThreadID].Free;
    ConnectionList.Remove(TThread.CurrentThread.ThreadID);
end;
```

Assim ao desconectar liberamos o objeto instanciado `TConexao` da memória através do método `Free` e em seguida removemos esse espaço do nosso dicionário. Poderiamos liberar a variável dicionário completamente da memória no evento `DataModuleDestroy` do `ServerContainer1`:

```
procedure TServerContainer1.DataModuleDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
    ConnectionList.Clear;
    ConnectionList.Destroy;
end;
```

Agora por fim para acessar os dados da sua unit `ServerMethods` basta adicionar no uses a unit `ServerConteiner`, e acessar o dicionário que é público, vejamos:

```
uses
    {unit já existentes...}, ServerConteiner;

{... declarações da unit ...}

function TServerMethods.ReverseString(Value: string): string;
begin
    // Acessando a seguir a informação para usar da forma que preferir.
    ServerContainer1.ConnectionList.[TThread.CurrentThread.ThreadID].IP;

    Result := System.StrUtils.ReverseString(Value);
end;
```

Seria basicamente isso, dessa forma você cria um caminho de passagem das informações de forma global no seu servidor de aplicação.